# SortedDictionary.TryGetValue() Overloads

Tags: c#, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I have a sorted dictionary using custom key structs. In order to facilitate sorting, I have some variable in the key that I dont want to participate in equality comparison.

An example of the class

```
public struct Key 
{
    //Needs to participate in equality comparison for SortedDictionary.TryGetValue();
    public int intKey;
    public object objectKey;

    //Needs to be ignored in SortedDictionary.TryGetValue();
    public int sortingVariable;
    public string otherSortingVariable;
}
```

I have tried overloading `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to the extent that `new Key().equals(new Key())` returns true.

However, `SortedDictionary.TryGetValue(new Key(), out Value)` returns false

Comment: How was the dictionary created? Did you pass a custom `IComparer<TKey>` to the constructor?

Comment: I can't recreate your problem, I tried a quick implementation of what you described and `TryGetValue(new Key(), out Value)` returns the right value. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @haim770 I forget to state that `Key` implements `IComparable<Key>`. However, the `CompareTo` function is used solely for sorting and will never return `0`

Comment: @DarkDestry did I misunderstand or is this approximatley what you have? https://dotnetfiddle.net/K13BtX

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It is more like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oxf1xY

I have changed line 12 and line 17

Comment: Huh ... well I guess it's not possible with a default SortedDictionary then. It looks like your `Equals` override has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yeah... I just peaked into the implementation of `ContainsKey` and see that they use the comparer for sorting as well as lookups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods you implemented are not used by sorted implementations. Instead, you need to either implement [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in your `struct`:

```
public struct Key : IComparable<Key> 
{
    public int CompareTo(Key other)
    {
        return Comparer.Default<string>.Compare(otherSortingVariable, other.otherSortingVariable);
    }
}
```

or a custom class implementing [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) interface:

```
public class KeyComparer : Comparer<Key>
{
    public override int Compare(Key x, Key y)
    {
        return Comparer.Default<string>.Compare(x.otherSortingVariable, y.otherSortingVariable);
    }
}
```

and pass an instance of the above class to the `SortedDictionary` constructor [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a045f865(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts custom comparer.

Comment: I forgot to state that I have already implemented that. But does this mean that it is using `CompareTo` in `TryGetValue`? How about `ContainKey`? Does this mean that both of those functions require a `0` to be returned for it to be equal?

Comment: Yes. In fact that's not specific to `SortedDictionary` and the forementioned  methods, but a requirement for correct `IComparable` / `IComparer` implementation. You should return 0 for equal, < 0 for less and > 0 for greater.

Comment: The reason for `CompareTo` not returning 0 is because it is comparing the sorting variables. It doesnt compare they key variables. The sorting variable is some independent variable that is used solely for sorting and is guaranteed to not be the same. Think of it like a UID associated with a Key. The UID will never be the same. However, I still need to identify an object in the list by using the key variables. I was hoping `Contains` uses equality operators that has nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: There is no way to use different comparison in one of the methods. The `SortedDictionary` uses one and the same consistent comparer for all operations. If you ignore some member in your comparer implementation, it will be ignored in all methods (`TryGetValue`, `Add`, `ContainsKey`, `indexer` etc.)

Comment: If the question is how to ignore that member **only** in `TryGetValue`, the answer is simply "you cannot do that".

Answer (score 1):

Since your `SortedDictionary` completely ignores the overrides you made and uses the `IComparable` interface to determine equality ([see this secion](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sorteddictionary.cs,df02b190dd5d9feb,references)) you can't use `TryGetValue`. You can however use your `Equals` method with Linq:

```
res = dict.Single(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(comperativeKey)).Value;
```

Unfortunately you loose all performance gains this way, so if that is an issue, you might want to implement you own custom Dictionary.

[Proof of Concept](https://dotnetfiddle.net/srp0M7)

Comment: I assume LINQ raises the time back to O(n)?

Comment: I guess so, if Linq is simple enumerating all elements until `Equals` returns true, it should scale linear.